# FROM Command in Docker File

Tags: docker

I would like understand the "FROM Command in Docker File" a little deep. 
Example: 
  I have installed docker on my centos.
  Now I have written a docker file like 
    FROM : ubuntu 
    ----file continues---
    --------
 In the above scenario, what is the use of FROM? Docker container will first download ubuntu OS and run my aplications on top of my ubuntu or centos?

I am little confused here, can someone please explain about this FROM?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Dockerfile docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from):

> The FROM instruction sets the Base Image for subsequent instructions. As such, a valid Dockerfile must have FROM as its first instruction.

So it's the first instruction in a Dockerfile and must exist; it tells Docker which is the base image on top of which all subsequent instructions will take place. Think of it as the base of a pizza which a (lazy) chef going to put in an oven. The chef buys the pizza base from a store and then add whatever the Chef wants on top of it and, with an oven, the chef will have a cooked pizza.

Now the important thing to understand is that if your base image is ubuntu you won't end up with the "ubuntu OS" downloaded but a (far smaller) snapshot of the Ubuntu filesystem, to quote [this Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/What-exactly-is-a-base-image-in-Docker/answer/Raseel-Bhagat?srid=Tqst):

> So a[n] Ubuntu base image is like a snapshot of a Ubuntu filesystem. So it does not have all the drivers installed on it like a full fledged hypervisor.

It's essentially the directories, binaries, config files, etc. that go on top/around of a Linux kernel.

Back to the pizza analogy (because: fun), your Docker host is the oven - it has all the beefy stuff needed to cook the pizza. So if your oven has a fancy self-cleaning function, then whatever chef is cooking the pizza will also have access to that.

If you haven't noticed already, you don't have to use a straight OS image, you can also use an application-focussed image. So if you're building Python, there's a python image. If you're doing Ruby, there's a ruby image.

In the end, I'd strongly recommend digging around for more information on Docker or LXC containers.

For an in-depth description, have a read of Docker's [Images and Containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/#images-and-layers) description.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response otuman:-). I would like to extnd my scenario now.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response otupman:-). I would like to extend my scenario now. Lets say I have installed docker in CentOS machine and in my docker file, I said FROM : CentOS. Now if I run the container on the same machine, will it download the CentOS again or Binaries only?  One more question : Shall I run this docker container in another VM where I did not installed Docker?

Comment: @Kishore.K your Docker host's OS more-or-less doesn't matter to your container. If you tell the container to use CentOS, it will use whatever is needed for that to happen. In most cases, esp. when you're starting out, you don't need to think about it. Just let it happen. Not sure what you mean by "shall I run ... in another VM where I did not install Docker'. A container can *only* run within Docker. I feel you're missing some basic concepts here, strongly recommend you watch a bunch of videos on Docker and find some good articles on it (sorry, I've none to hand).

Answer (score 0):

the Dockerfile directive FROM means that when you do

`docker build .`

using this Dockerfile, the image ubuntu:latest, will be used.

So either you have it locally, so

`docker images ubuntu`

will show it

or it will be downloaded when you build a new image using

`FROM ubuntu`

Yes, Docker automatically downloads the base image you specify in your Dockerfile

The reference doc

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from